# JS: Variable returning undefined except defining it earlier

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

My code is

```
var api_url

$.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", function(e) {
    myIP = e.ip;
    //api_url = "https://cors-anywhere-ctrack.herokuapp.com/https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=" + myIP
});

//api_url = "https://cors-anywhere-ctrack.herokuapp.com/https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=" + myIP

function geoloc() {
  api_url = "https://cors-anywhere-ctrack.herokuapp.com/https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=" + myIP
  console.log(api_url)
  const response = await fetch(api_url)
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data)
}

geoloc();
```

I fired it up with python 3's http.server and it printed `"https://cors-anywhere-ctrack.herokuapp.com/https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=undefined"` and the fetch, as expected, failed. Upon closer inspection the variable myIP was defined. I feel like It has something to do with async and await but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you're using async/await then your `geoloc` function should be declared as `async function geoloc()`.

Comment: @lawrence-witt Sorry for the confusion. I'm not sure how I can apply async / await or if I should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyjkzqcf/

You can call `geoloc()` in `$.getJSON()` method. Please have a look below:

```js
 var api_url
    
    $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", function(e) {
        myIP = e.ip;
        geoloc();
        //api_url = "https://cors-anywhere-ctrack.herokuapp.com/https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=" + myIP
    });
    
    //api_url = "https://cors-anywhere-ctrack.herokuapp.com/https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=" + myIP
    
    async function geoloc() {
      api_url = "https://cors-anywhere-ctrack.herokuapp.com/https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=" + myIP
      console.log(api_url)
      const response = await fetch(api_url)
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyjkzqcf/ there is no error and u need to make function async @MilkyDeveloper

Comment: Huh. It works out of my precious localhost server and in a repl / jsfiddle. Thanks! Surprised how SO users are so quick to respond.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
async function geoloc() {
  api_url = "https://cors-anywhere-ctrack.herokuapp.com/https://tools.keycdn.com/geo.json?host=" + myIP
  console.log(api_url)
  const response = await fetch(api_url)
  const data = response.json();
  console.log(data)
}
```

Declare function as `async` and `await` only once.